# How to find an analysis of a classical piece in the internet

Tags: piano, analysis

I'm a passionate non-professional musician and I find it extremely helpful to know something more about the pieces I practice. I tried to find musical analyses (formal, rhythmical, melodical) in the internet but it was completely impossible. (I look for analyses of Schubert's first and Rachmaninov's second piano trio.)

Does anybody have some advice where to look for analyses of classical pieces?

EDIT: To clarify: I'm looking for a list of webpages where one can find analyses of many classical pieces.

Comment: Reading analysis is actually quite helpful for learning music theory and developing analysis techniques. Reading others' analysis also gives different perspectives than limited self interpretation learnt from a book.

Comment: Why do you need to use the internet? It is full of unreliable information. It's become the default source for all information and education-that's not a good thing. Music Theory, Analysis, and Musicology are not new subjects. Many good books have been written on all the subjects you are interested in, by experts in the various fields. Read them: Borrow them from a  library or buy them: There are now a great many eBooks-available for Kindle, etc. Musical knowledge is difficult to acquire and it's time and labor consuming to write well and knowledgeably about music - so it's worth paying for.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking in the wrong place. There are many printed books on the subjects you are interested in, in libraries. These books have been written since the time of Schubert and Rachmaninov, but their contents have not made it onto the Internet.

For example, I did a [quick search at Google Books to find references to old books in libraries for "rachmaninoff form analysis"](https://www.google.com/search?q=rachmaninoff%20form%20analysis&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) and I came up with a bibliography of dozens of books on the subject -- books which you should go looking for in a large public library or university music library.

Comment: Or IMSLP for at least some: http://imslp.org/index.php?title=Category:Music_analysis&transclude=Template:Catintro. Internet Archive for even more: https://archive.org/details/texts?and[]=music%20analysis.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Are there similar links?

Comment: Don't know, but you have maybe a better idea of the _kind_ of links to look for now, eh?

Answer (score 0):

The appeal of the internet is that books do not play back music and it is very important to hear examples along with written/spoken words.  The classic textbook by Kostka is great but with such books, it is a bit of work to play the CD along w the book or strip the CD and go back and forth with a computer to play as you read.   http://openmusictheory.com is a good site but I feel like a lot of books and sites do not offer as many examples as they should, for brevity.  Great composers became great thru many many examples.