# How to find efficiently and systematically audiovisual analysis of pieces?

Tags: analysis

An elderly relative's debility inhibits  reading [music analysis only in writing](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/29209/26407): so it is off-topic.

I mean 'audiovisual analysis' as analysis of pieces with music history and theory in video with audio, like Japanese pianist Kotaro Fukuma's helpful videos on [Bartok's Piano Concerto no. 2](https://youtu.be/viChk3wo6rk) and [Ligeti's only Piano Concerto](https://youtu.be/mfTDjrndPH). Particularly helpful are his on-screen:

1. transcriptions of important music theory terms.
2. reproductions of parts of scores that he explains or samples by playing on the piano.

How can such analysis be found efficiently, without Googling each piece?

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities that you may find interesting:

1. The Society for Music Theory, the international community for our field, recently began a [videocast journal](https://societymusictheory.org/smt-v) called SMT-V. It's still new, so there aren't many videos, but you can currently find analyses of Mozart, video game music, and Schumann. And even though it isn't analysis, I'll particularly recommend the [Repetition and Musicality](https://vimeo.com/120517523) video.
2. On the other side of the pond, the Society for Music Analysis also has some [video podcasts](http://www.sma.ac.uk/videos/introduction/). Their videos are:

   - Why do we analyse music?
   - Aspects of popular music
   - Analysing musical time
   - Analysis in context
3. Lastly, occasionally [Music Theory Online](http://www.mtosmt.org/index.php), the online journal for the Society for Music Theory, includes audiovisual analyses. [This one](http://www.mtosmt.org/issues/mto.09.15.1/mto.09.15.1.roeder_signification.html) looks at a Bartók Scherzo, Op. 14, No. 2, and I bet it's a type of analysis that's new to most on this site!

These videos are a bit different than what you're looking for, but I still thought I'd offer them, considering no one else has answered in quite some time.